# How do you check for matching value in third column based on distinct combinations of other two columns?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table with Building name, such as A, B, C. These building names could be repeated. I have another column which has the floor. Such as floor 1 ,floor 2. Again there could be multiple floor 1 for every building. There is a third column which has object present such as television, bricks, fans.
I want to check for every combination of building with corresponding floors, such as Building A - floor 1, Building A- floor 2, if an object 'brick' exists then 'wall' must exist.

EXAMPLE DATA:
For every building and location, if 'WALL' exists , 'WINDOW', 'WINDOW1' or 'WINDOW2' must exist, ELSE FLAG

```
BUILDING  LOCATION  OBJECT   
A         FLOOR1    WALL
A         FLOOR1    WINDOW  
A         FLOOR2    WALL  
B         FLOOR1    WALL  
C         FLOOR1    WALL  
C         FLOOR1    WINDOW
```

DESIRED OUPUT

```
BUILDING  LOCATION  ACTION  

A         FLOOR2    FLAG
B         FLOOR1    FLAG
```

I have tried using GROUP BY, DISTINCT, WHERE EXISTS, but I cant seem to come up with the right logic.

Comment: update your question add  a clear data sample and the expected  result

Comment: @scaisEdge Added

Comment: Shouldn't it be `C` instead of `B` in the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `group by building, location` for the rows `where object in ('WALL', 'WINDOW')`:

```
select building, location, 'FLAG' action
from tablename
where object in ('WALL', 'WINDOW')
group by building, location
having count(distinct object) < 2
```

The condition `count(distinct object) < 2` in the `having` clause returns combination of `building, location` where `'WALL'` and `'WINDOW'` do not both exist.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bGYXpTW6tUtN9EhH3VhnYU/0).
Results:

```
| building | location | action |
| -------- | -------- | ------ |
| A        | FLOOR2   | FLAG   |
| B        | FLOOR1   | FLAG   |
```

Or with NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.building, t.location, 'FLAG' action
from tablename t
where object in ('WALL', 'WINDOW')
and not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where building = t.building and location = t.location and object <> t.object
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bGYXpTW6tUtN9EhH3VhnYU/1).

Comment: This works but I have also updated my question. What if you need to check for multiple values? How would you do this?

Comment: This answers the original question. If you have another question post it.

Answer (score 0):

nested tables is what you want.  Something like

```
select column_3
from (
  select *
  from table
  where table.column_3="brick"
) as e
join table t on t.id = e.id
where table.column_3="window"
```

fyi: I reccomend you use this as a start, but for your exact case, id imagine this needs to be modified