# How do you grouby and check if group contains 2 or more of the given values?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with Building name, such as A, B, C. These building names could be repeated. I have another column which has the floor. Such as floor 1 ,floor 2. Again there could be multiple floor 1 for every building. There is a third column which has object present such as television, bricks, fans.
I want to check for every combination of building with corresponding floors, such as Building A - floor 1, Building A- floor 2, if an object 'brick' exists then 'wall' must exist.

EXAMPLE DATA:
For every building and location, if 'WALL' exists , 'WINDOW', 'WINDOW1' or 'WINDOW2' must exist, ELSE FLAG

```
BUILDING  LOCATION  OBJECT   
A         FLOOR1    WINDOW1  
A         FLOOR1    WINDOW  
A         FLOOR1    WINDOW2 
A         FLOOR2    WALL  
B         FLOOR1    WALL  
C         FLOOR1    WALL  
C         FLOOR1    WINDOW
```

DESIRED OUPUT

```
BUILDING  LOCATION  ACTION    
A         FLOOR2    FLAG
B         FLOOR1    FLAG
```

I have tried using GROUP BY, DISTINCT, WHERE EXISTS, but I cant seem to come up with the right logic.

Comment: @forpas This is the new question!

Comment: What is the difference to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56600496/how-do-you-check-for-matching-value-in-third-column-based-on-distinct-combinatio)?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I want to compare to check for a list of values like Window,Window1,Window2. At least one should exist. I had updated the previous one. But got that back to the original question and created this

Comment: I don't understand how the "DESIRED OUPUT" corresponds to "For every building and location, if 'WALL' exists , 'WINDOW', 'WINDOW1' or 'WINDOW2' must exist, ELSE FLAG". Also - What does "ELSE FLAG" mean?

Comment: For A -  FLOOR1, no wall exists, so it does not matter. For A- FLOOR2 , a wall exists hence either one of the windows must exist. But it doesnt so you select that records and add "FLAG" in a new column. Same for B FLOOR1. Incase of C FLOOR 1 there is a wall but also a window hence it does not need to be flagged. @PaulSpiegel

Comment: So you want to return combinations of (BUILDING, LOCATION) having `'WALL'` as OBJECT but not having `'WINDOW'` nor `'WINDOW1'` nor `'WINDOW2'`?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Yess!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/25hyUh26vHxySPfeyV11qP/0)**

```
SELECT building, 
        location,  
        MAX(CASE WHEN object = 'WALL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as has_walls,
        MAX(CASE WHEN object IN ('WINDOW', 'WINDOW1', 'WINDOW2') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as has_windows
 FROM tablename
 GROUP BY building, location
 HAVING 
        has_walls <> has_windows;
```

so if You have any wall the `MAX()` will return 1, same for windows.

This bring the `WALL` without `WINDOWS` but also bring the `WINDOWS` without `WALLS`

Let me know if you need more refining

If you want `WALLS` without `WINDOWS`

```
 SELECT building, 
        location,  
        MAX(CASE WHEN object = 'WALL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as has_walls,
        MAX(CASE WHEN object IN ('WINDOW', 'WINDOW1', 'WINDOW2') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as has_windows
 FROM tablename
 GROUP BY building, location
 HAVING 
        has_walls > 0 
    AND has_windows = 0
```

Comment: You know, you can use column alises in the HAVING clause? At least in MySQL.

Comment: Well the true is I add the columns on the SELECT after adding the HAVING to show the result more clear.

Answer (score 1):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select distinct t.building, t.location, 'FLAG' action
from tablename t
where object = 'WALL'
and not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where building = t.building and location = t.location
  and object like 'WINDOW%'
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bGYXpTW6tUtN9EhH3VhnYU/7).
Results:

```
| building | location | action |
| -------- | -------- | ------ |
| A        | FLOOR2   | FLAG   |
| B        | FLOOR1   | FLAG   |
```

Comment: I've wrote almost the same, but the result didn't match the desired output until it has been fixed in the question. Though I used `rlike 'WINDOW[0-9]*'`.

Comment: `*` means zero or one or many times. So it does match 'WINDOW' too. Don't understand my comment wrong. I just verified your solution as valid.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel you're right. I misread the rlike pattern (too much sql server focused).

Answer (score 0):

I actually would write the query the same way as forpas did. But here is another way:

```
select BUILDING, LOCATION, 'FLAG' as `ACTION`
from my_table
group by BUILDING, LOCATION
having bit_or(OBJECT = 'WALL') -- at least one OBJECT is 'WALL'
   and bit_and(OBJECT not rlike 'WINDOW[0-9]*') -- no OBJECT matches 'WINDOW[number]'
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x1RgeKoPXzbaEDBXNg666n/0)

It's shorter, but might be not trivial to understand.